# Solr boost based on live_date, title and keywords

Tags: solr, runtime

I want to boost the content based on live_date, also title and keyword.

1) I can boost title and keyword by using qf and pf:

```
?q=mySearchTerm&fl=id,title,live_date,content,score&sort=score desc&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0
```

2) I can boost live_date by using function to calculate live_datetime to now and apply the recip function:

```
?q={!boost b=$recency v=$qq}&recency=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)&qq="mysearchTerm"&sort=score desc
```

3) How can I combine the 1) and 2) so that I can boost live_date + title and keyword at the same time? I tried this but failed.  Can anyone point out the issue here? thanks.

```
?q={!boost b=$recency v=$qq}&recency=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)
&qq="mysearchTerm"&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score
```

Please advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a boost function like:

?q="mysearchTerm"&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score&bf=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)^5

Comment: Cool, this is working good with solr1.4.1 with defType=dismax. I will implement this idea for now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ?q={!boost b=$recency v=$qq}&recency=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)
> &qq="mysearchTerm"&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0
> keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score
> ```

Based on the examples that you say *do* work, i suspect you have "defType=dismax" or"defType=edismax" configured for your request handler in solrconfig.xml -- that's the only reason that your example #1 would pay attention to your qf and pf params.

defType only applies to parsing the main query of the current context (ie: "q" in the top level request; v in a subquery), and in your examples #2 and #3 you are using the localparam syntax to override that.  In order to ensure that your "qq" param is parsed using dismax/edismax, you need to specify defType as a local param for the context that qq is being parsed in...

```
?q={!boost b=$recency defType=edismax v=$qq}&recency=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)&qq="mysearchTerm"&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score
...OR...
?q={!boost b=$recency defType=dismax v=$qq}&recency=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)&qq="mysearchTerm"&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score
```

Alternatively, if you are using edismax, then instead of using the "boost" QParser to wrap the "edismax" QParser, you can use the "boost" param of the edismax parser to accomplish the same thing in a simpler syntax...

```
?q="mysearchTerm"&boost=recip(ms(NOW/HOUR,live_datetime),3.16e-11,0.08,0.05)&qf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&pf=title^2.0 keywords^1.2 content^1.0&fl=live_datetime,score
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but it seems edismas only works for solr3.1+, we are still on solr1.4.1 now. but I will use your last suggestion after we get upgraded. Thanks.

Comment: Jeff: the initial suggestion i posted works fine for dismax as well (edited to try and make this more clear) .. only the last suggestion requires edismax.